# How to "hint" the type of an empty list in python

Tags: python, list, type-hinting

I have a Class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._subscribers = []
```

and i want to specify the type that will go into the list 'self._subscribers'. for example a queue.Queue() object. but the list should still be an empty list.

just for ease of use in PyCharm

```
self._subscribers = [queue.Queue]
self._subscribers = list[queue.Queue]
```

both don't seem to work

thanks

PS.: Python 3.64

Comment: This is not a duplicate of those questions. The other questions are about type hinting function _arguments_.

Comment: To answer the question: `self._subscribers = [] # type: List[Monitor]`